# Определение города/региона России по IP (актуальное в 2019 году)

Tags: php, ip

Требуется определение в первую очередь региона пользователя (только Россия) на стороне сервера по IP. Желательна точность 95% и выше, но возможен и компромисс с точностью 80-90%. Подскажите какой бесплатный сервис с приемлемыми лимитами запросов наиболее точный для России, желательно с примерами запросов. Держать и актуализировать на сервере собственную базу IP в данном проекте не вариант.

Смотрел в сторону Яндекс.Локатора, но нашел получение только гео-координат, DaData обещает не очень высокую точность (50–75%).

Comment: Недавно столкнулся, что мой ip определяется как Краснодар, хотя нахожусь в Ростове, вот уже 2 года так.... О какой точности может идти речь.... Точность 50-75 в самый раз

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev насколько я знаю особо низкая точность IP при использовании сотовых провайдеров - у меня проект заточен под пользователей ПК, надеюсь у "наземных" провайдеров точность будет выше.

Comment: Не в моём случаи, у меня "наземный" провайдер. При чём до этого 3 года я "жил" в Москве, и это очень бесило, так как на многих сайтов сбивался ранее выбранный регион/город. Ранее когда я делал определение городов/регионов на сайте, я фиксировал сколько раз нажималась кнопка "Уточнить местоположение", и нажатий было много. Процентов 40.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, ну может сайты и пытались определять IP по кривым базам, а по нормальным определялось нормально. Если просто загуглить на тему определения по IP то в первую очередь вывалиться куча международных гео-сервисов с сомнительной точностью и актуальностью баз. Именно поэтому я и задал такой вопрос, а не взял решения по первым попавшимся ссылкам. Надежда есть например на API Яндекса, который может вести базу не просто по диапазонам провайдеров, а по живым пользователям (таким как ты - "уточнившем местоположение").

Comment: Ну если яндекс игнорировал 3 года, и теперь уже игнорирует 2 года... то я сомневаюсь, что им нужна точность. Они определили, а там уже всё возложено на пользователя. Но пока я не видел ни одной базы и сервиса, где бы была точность хотя бы 80%.

Comment: @Nsk у билайна вы будете летать между тверью и питером не находясь ни там ни там. Лучше начать с дадата и уточнять данные у пользователя

Answer (score 3):

Варианты:

1) IpGeoBase.ru (лучше использовать через nikolaevevgeGeoIp для кеширования запросов и IpGeoBase не предоставляет по API геокоординат)

2) Supex Geo

3) встроенное в php https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.geoip.php

Про всё можно почитать тут http://blog.ivru.net/?id=82

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Для этого лучше воспользоватся базой данных maxmind или использовать API, например, https://ipwhois.io/ (есть поддержка русского языка).

Comment: Человеку нужна точность 90%, я через ваш сервис в Самаре живу, а по факту в Ростове.

Answer (score 0):

После получения координат Яндекс может определить город/регион.

Подключаем [yandex-php/php-yandex-locator](https://github.com/yandex-php/php-yandex-locator), получаем координаты:

```
function getCoordinatesByIp($ip)
{
    $api = new \Yandex\Locator\Api('КЛЮЧ АПИ');
    $api->setIp($ip);

    try {
        $api->load();

        $response = $api->getResponse();

        if ($response->getLatitude() && $response->getLongitude()) {
            return [
                'latitude' => $response->getLatitude(),
                'longitude' => $response->getLongitude(),
            ];
        }

    } catch (\Yandex\Locator\Exception $ex) {

    }

    return false;
}
```

Подключаем [yandex-php/php-yandex-geo](https://github.com/yandex-php/php-yandex-geo), получаем город и регион:

```
function getLocationByCoordinates($longitude, $latitude)
{
    $api = new \Yandex\Geo\Api();
    $api->setPoint($longitude, $latitude);

    try {
        $api
            ->setLimit(1)
            ->setLang(\Yandex\Geo\Api::LANG_RU)
            ->load();

        $data = $api->getResponse()->getFirst()->getData();

        return [
            'region'=> $data['AdministrativeAreaName'] ?? false,
            'city'=> $data['LocalityName'] ?? false,
        ];

    } catch (\Yandex\Geo\Exception $exception){

    }

    return false;
}
```